# Dell XPS 14 9434 laptop Wifi Adapter Disabled and I can't enable it?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I have a Dell XPS 13 9343 Laptop onto which I have installed Linux alongside the Windows 8.1 OS it came with. This worked fine first time but last night after I caused a Kernel Panic I decided to reinstall knowing how easy and quick it was.

God was I wrong, now the Wifi will not work and I can't seem to fix it. According to 'lshw' this is the current status of the adapter AFTER installing the proprietary drivers from the System Setting GUI.

> ```
>    *-network DISABLED   
>    description: Wireless interface
>    product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
>    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>    physical id: 0
>    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
>    logical name: wlan0
>    version: 03
>    serial: c4:8e:8f:f7:fc:5b
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
>    resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
> ```

Comment: [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/661035/edit) to include the results from `rfkill list all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to be solving my own problems after posting a lot these days. Though I am not sure exactly what I did that fixed it, here is everything I did as reference.

- Removed and Purged the Drivers entirely, rebooted to be sure.
- `sudo rfkill unblock all` and other commands associated with this (google is full of them) eg: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
- I could not find any other drivers interfering with the Wifi so ruled this out.
- Finally I found a post mentioning `gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and changing a value from false to true
- Finally restart the NM `sudo service network-manager restart`

These last 2 steps were what I was missing but I'm not sure what else I did that contributed.

This page also had lots of useful info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411216

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you haven't disabled the Wi-Fi (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>).