# On Dell XPS 9343 Linux 15.10, wi-fi hardware unavailable all of a sudden

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

Was always working fine with:
Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Not completely sure if problem was there already but I once got out of battery (which was maybe first time ever...), maybe that is when problem started. Anyway, tried deinstall and reinstall of drivers, and suggestions done here
[Dell XPS 14 9434 laptop Wifi Adapter Disabled and I can't enable it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661035/dell-xps-14-9434-laptop-wifi-adapter-disabled-and-i-cant-enable-it/)
 (and in the links mentioned therein, o.a. rfkill unblock all). But still I can not switch on the wifi.

It is looking grim right now.

Answer (score 0):

With shortkeys: Fn + PrtScr  you can toggle the wifi of your dell xps 9343 on/ off. Solved...